# cannot convert yyyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd - arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to do something that is very simple and am stumped why it is not working.

I have a column (`sysjobschedules.next_run_date` from `msdb`) that is a varchar formatted like yyyymmdd.  I want to convert that to a datetime.  I use the rather straight-forward command `CONVERT(datetime,next_run_date,112)` but I keep getting the error **Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.**

The three distinct values in this column are 20120802, 20120803, and 20120806.  Using that same function above, I was able to successfully convert all three strings.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column is actually stored as an int, and it means something different in datetime, so you'll need one extra step in your CONVERT:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), next_run_date), 112);
```

To show why you can't do this directly to an int:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0);
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 1);
```

When it's an int, it's actually the number of days since 1900-01-01.

Comment: Bingo - I can't believe I overlooked this.  Thanks!!